# Select transformando registros diferentes em único

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso fazer um select unificando duas linhas diferentes em uma só, com duas novas colunas.

Estou utilizando bd oracle e não há possibilidade de realizar update nas tabelas.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você talvez consiga isso usando a função `PIVOT` do Oracle:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT carro, ano, preco
  FROM sua_tabela
)
PIVOT
(
  sum(preco)
  FOR ano IN (2016, 2017, 2018)
)
ORDER BY carro;
```